# align graph nodes in several swimlines

Tags: algorithm, workflow, graph, flowchart

I want to align certain graph nodes into several 'lanes' like this

[image: foo]
<sub>(source: [jiscinfonet.ac.uk](http://www.jiscinfonet.ac.uk/InfoKits/process-review/swim-lanes))</sub>

Any suitable algorithms (like force-based algorithms in general graph drawing)?

Answer (score 1):

You can coerce [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to draw what you want, and you should be able to call the libraries fairly easily.  The homepage of their site has some useful references on the algorithms used.